# I Thought + Present or Past Tense to be Used

Tags: sentence-construction

I was on leave and went to the office for some reason. At the office my friend asked me:

> Why you are in the office today? I thought you **are** on leave.

It sounded weird to me. He used the present tense after the past tense "thought". Is it OK if we construct the sentence this way or should the sentence be like:

> Why are you in the office today? I thought you **were** on leave.

One more sentence in this context:

> I thought you **were**/**are** coming late today.

Comment: Either say: "How come you are in the office today?" or "Why are you in the office today?" I thought (past tense) you were on leave.

Comment: [I sounded weary.] I thought you were on leave. leave is not holiday.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as **agreement of tenses** (amongst other names). [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses):

> If the main verb of a sentence is in the past tense, then other verbs must also express a past viewpoint, except when a general truth is being expressed.

So you are correct that the second verb should also have been in the past tense:

> I **thought** you **were** on leave.
>
> I **thought** you **were** coming late today.

These are the correct way to say these sentences.

If the second part of the sentence is a general truth, then the present tense is used:

> I thought the Earth **is** flat, now I know it's round.

Comment: "I thought the Earth is flat, now I know it's round." This sounds incorrect. "I thought the Earth **was** flat, **but** now..." sounds more accurate. Could you explain why you've picked your current sentence structure?

Comment: @Corsaka I wasn't entirely happy with that when I wrote it. Perhaps: "I thought lions **eat** plants, now I know they eat animals."

Comment: I think what "If the second part of the sentence is a general truth, then the present tense is used" means is when the second part is a general truth, use the present in the second part only, i.e: I thought lions **ate** plants, now I know they **eat** animals.

Comment: @Corsaka I wrote that sentence myself. It is not found in the Wikipedia article. I agree that your sentence is **also** possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well , grammatically yes ..  it's like saying

> John could ride horses better than anyone

Which is correct .. it will have no meanings if we say john *could rode* ...

> .. i thought you *are* on leave

**Means** in the last few hours i was thinking youre on leave

> I thought you were coming late today

**Were+verb-ing** is correct affer a past tense

Another explanation : as i said in the situation you mentioned **are** is correct ,  but if your friend means that i kinda figured out that you were not on leave yesterday he must say it like this

> .. I thought you **were** on leave

Hope i helped ..